# How to handle a web element getting removed from DOM using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of label that has the xpath as xpath=".//*[@id='msgIdmmrka']" on Sign In page of http://www.overstock.com. But this web element is removed from the DOM after few seconds when I enter no email, valid password and click the Sign In button.

I'm new to Selenium Webdriver, so could not think of a solution on how to handle this scenario? Could you please help me with this?

I get the below exception error message when trying to find this web element

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='msgIdmmrka']"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.19 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'Srinivasans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=43.0.3, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 724463ca-6ab8-f246-acb4-6c8d955e066c
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='msgIdmmrka']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wait for message element to be visible* after submitting a form:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".page-errors .message")));
```

The `.page-errors .message` CSS selector would match the error message.

Comment: I still get the same exception.

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu you cannot get the same exception unless you still have that `findElement()` call in the code.

Comment: @alexce I updated the code as WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("msgIdmmrka"))); Now I get a message saying "Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: msgIdmmrka"

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu okay, but why are you waiting for an element with id instead of using the selector I've suggested?